# Obstacles, and Can Tenser's Floating Disk move around corners?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The description of the Tenser's Floating Disk spell says:

> This spell creates a circular, horizontal plane of force, 3 feet in diameter and 1 inch thick, that floats 3 feet above the ground in an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see within range. The disk remains for the Duration, and can hold up to 500 pounds. If more weight is placed on it, the spell ends, and everything on the disk falls to the ground.
>
> The disk is immobile while you are within 20 feet of it. If you move more than 20 feet away from it, the disk follows you so that it remains within 20 feet of you. It can move across uneven terrain, up or down stairs, slopes and the like, but it can't cross an elevation change of 10 feet or more. For example, the disk can't move across a 10-foot-deep pit, nor could it leave such a pit if it was created at the bottom.
>
> If you move more than 100 feet from the disk (typically because it can't move around an obstacle to follow you), the spell ends.

Tenser's Floating Disk follows you at a distance of 20 feet and can't move around obstacles. What counts as an obstacle? Suppose you are walking down a narrow corridor that turns a corner:

D = disk; W = wizard; * = wall; . = space between wizard and disc;
Each space is a 5' square:

```
*********  *********
D...W-> *     -> D.*
******* *  *******.*
      * *        *.*
      * *        *W*
```

Does the corner prevent the disk from following you?

If so, would it only be possible to get the disk around the corner if you first moved straight for 20 feet, like making a wide turn in a semi truck? If so, it seems rather useless in some circumstances.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm completely understanding you: are you asking whether TFD is following the [pursuit path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve) of the wizard and, therefore, would get "hung up" if the wizard unintentionally interposes an obstacle due to the 20' maintained distance?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you interpret in the spell description to mean that the disc "can't move around obstacles"?

Comment: @Marq "If you move more than 100 feet from the disk (typically because it can't move around an obstacle to follow you), the spell ends."

Comment: @nitsua60 Yes, is TFD following the pursuit path? Since TFD stays immobile while you are within 20 feet of it, it would seem logical that it would follow you directly along the pursuit path the moment you leave that range, regardless of whatever movement you did while in range.

Answer (score 15):

## Yes!

There are no limitations to directional lateral movement per the spell language. Vertical movement is only limited by elevation changes of greater than 10 feet.

As long as there isn't a vertical elevation change greater than 10', the Disk will follow you wherever you may roam.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, the disk can navigate tight corners.

Understanding the limits of English grammar, I think the text you cited contains the most important part in supporting the "It can make turns" idea:

> If you move more than 20 feet away from it, the disk **follows you** so that it remains within 20 feet of you.

Although this could be construed by a DM as "the disk attempts to move directly towards you to keep the separation distance at 20 feet," it literally indicates that the disk follows you, such as following your path around a corner.